# IBX TIBDatabase.GetTableNames doesn't show a newly created table

Tags: delphi, firebird

If I create a new table in my Firebird database, and then I call:

TIBDatabase.GetTableNames, the newly created table doesn't get enunmerated: I have first to issue:

```
IBDatabase1.Connected := False;
IBDatabase1.Connected := True;
```

and then I can call TIBDatabase.GetTableNames and have the newly created table enumerated.

The following function uses TIBDatabase.GetTableNames to determine the existence of a given table name passed as parameter

```
function TableExists(const aTableName: String): Boolean;
var
  ListOfExistingTables: TStringList;
begin
  Result:= False;
  ListOfExistingTables:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    IBDatabase1.GetTableNames(ListOfExistingTables);
    Result:= (ListOfExistingTables.IndexOf(aTableName) > - 1);
  finally
    ListOfExistingTables.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firebird even Metadata-changes are isolated in transactions. So you have to commit the transaction, which you have used to create the table. Maybe you have to commit the transaction which is uses by IBX to read the table-names, too.

Comment: Thak you very much! I issued   if IBTransaction1.InTransaction then
    IBTransaction1.Commit; and all is working like a charm now!